# Javascript: Target only the parent item and leave siblings alone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Javascript and I've been wracking my brains trying to figure out what I guess should be quite simple:

I'm using Twitter bootstrap and have an accordion of collapsible panels. I've added two extra divs to the panel heading within the class 'panel_button': One containing the text 'Open' and one containing 'Close'. I want to obviously toggle which is displayed when clicked, but I don't know how to target only the parent panel without the siblings being triggered also. Here is my code:

=====

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading clearfix closed" role="tab" id="headingOne">
  <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">Panel Heading 1</a></h4>
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="panel_button">
    <div class="open_link_content">Open</div>
    <div class="close_link_content" style="display:none;">Close</div>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
  <div class="panel-body">Panel Content 1</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading clearfix closed" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Panel Heading 2</a></h4>
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="panel_button">
  <div class="open_link_content">Open</div>
  <div class="close_link_content" style="display:none;">Close</span></div>
</a>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
<div class="panel-body">Panel Content 2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

====

I realise this won't work but it's as far as I've got:

```
<script>
  $(".panel-title , .panel_button").click(function(){
      $(".close_link_content").toggle();
      $(".open_link_content").toggle();
  });
</script>
```

Hopefully there is a simple solution out there. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap's show/hide events and show open or close links depending on them:

```
$('.panel').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    $(this).find(".close_link_content").hide();
    $(this).find(".open_link_content").show();
})

$('.panel').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    $(this).find(".close_link_content").show();
    $(this).find(".open_link_content").hide();
})
```

Here I've set up an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/coq5dh98/2/) from your code

Comment: Aha - well, in my haste I thought it was what I needed. It works, but both panels show the 'Close' div even when just one is open. Ideally, I would need only the activated panel to trigger the show/hide event.

Comment: then you should simply search within the collapsible panel, like this: `$(this).find(".close_link_content").hide();`

Comment: YES!! That works beautifully (and is a whole lot less code than the lumbering beast I had come up with). Much appreciated! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% what you're trying to do. My best guess is to open the panel below each heading on click?

In that case just update the href in the second link to :

```
href="#collapseTwo"
```

If you do need to access the parent of an element 
`$("element").parent()`

Hopefully this helps you,

Pete

Comment: Thanks, Pete. Maybe I didn't describe the problem too well. The collapsible accordion works fine, it's just getting the '.close_link_content'(i.e. show the text 'Close') or '.open_link_content'(i.e. show the text 'Open')...to be activated when that panel is clicked, without the Javascript triggering that class for all the panels.

Comment: Hi, just saw this now but glad you got the answer you need

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
$(".panel-title , .panel_button").click(function () {

            if ($(this).hasClass("panel-title")) {
                var href = $(this).children("a").attr("href")  
            } else {
                var href = $(this).attr("href")
            }

            $(href).toggle()
            if ($(href + ":visible").length) {
                $(href).prev().find(".open_link_content").show()
                $(href).prev().find(".close_link_content").hide()
            } else {
                $(href).prev().find(".open_link_content").hide()
                $(href).prev().find(".close_link_content").show()
            }

        });
```

but pay attention: second element in html may be

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" class="panel_button">
```